# FilterConfig - OnAuthorization excluding AJAX Calls

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi have a filter on my ASP.NET MVC website named **MyClassAuthorizationAttribute** :

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new MyClassAuthorizationAttribute());
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class MyClassAuthorizationAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && 
            filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName != "LogOut")
        {
            //Code Here
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see everytime a controller action is executed this code runs. My concern is that I have some controller actions that are used only on AJAX calls, and even those off course raise this filter, however I don't want that to happen.

Is there anyway to avoid or do any filtering on the **OnAuthorization** to not catch those AJAX calls?

I am trying to avoid manually creating a list of Ajax actions to check inside my **OnAuthorization** method.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an if-statement inside your OnAuthorization filter to check if the request is of non-ajax type:

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && 
            filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName != "LogOut")
        {
            //Code Here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need !! Thanks a lot, so fast ! I will mark it as accepted within 10 min.